# CSS auto hyphens turn into question-mark boxes in Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I use some automatic hyphenation with CSS on my website:

```
article > p,
article > li {
  -o-hyphens: auto;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-before: 3;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-after: 3;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-chars: 6 3 3;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-lines: 2;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-last: always;
  -o-hyphenate-limit-zone: 8%;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: 3;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: 3;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-chars: 6 3 3;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines: 2;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-last: always;
  -webkit-hyphenate-limit-zone: 8%;
  
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphenate-limit-chars: 6 3 3;
  -moz-hyphenate-limit-lines: 2;
  -moz-hyphenate-limit-last: always;
  -moz-hyphenate-limit-zone: 8%;
  
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphenate-limit-chars: 6 3 3;
  -ms-hyphenate-limit-lines: 2;
  -ms-hyphenate-limit-last: always;
  -ms-hyphenate-limit-zone: 8%;

  hyphens: auto;
  hyphenate-limit-before: 3;
  hyphenate-limit-after: 3;
  hyphenate-limit-chars: 6 3 3;
  hyphenate-limit-lines: 2;
  hyphenate-limit-last: always;
  hyphenate-limit-zone: 8%;
}
```

This works fine in Safari and Firefox:

[image]

It does not work fine in Chrome and Opera:

[image]

I use Gatsby JS.

UTF-8 is set correctly.

HTML example:

```
<html lang="no" data-react-helmet="lang">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <style data-href="/styles.09a8a5848dd0eb9f410a.css" data-identity="gatsby-global-css">@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse-index;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;src:url(/static/concourse-index-0e58827a8225cf99f069d1596d4a63aa.woff2)}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:300;src:url(/static/concourse-thin-246af84cfbd6584fb430db5c66a97969.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:300;src:url(/static/concourse-thin-italic-9e4f4d97206038fd0c3b8cc89eaa8080.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/concourse-book-73f05e9965360db03328417c782a9d19.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/concourse-book-italic-dbbcddd329d01cf3697b131212819ed8.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:500;src:url(/static/concourse-medium-b07cd86f641812a197784622ba6647ef.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:500;src:url(/static/concourse-medium-italic-793c5314eb4aa99cca7f817e13e28c91.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:600;src:url(/static/concourse-semibold-e04597eb296c2b58303cd638bcf280f1.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:600;src:url(/static/concourse-semibold-italic-34295165e42193dd8e992993dfc7390c.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/concourse-bold-692eae572ac17070acbd577819bc0cb5.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse-bold-italic;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/concourse-bold-italic-1df4d1201a389a56f1015c18c8d62fca.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:900;src:url(/static/concourse-black-fb0c672d3ca1fd93c8b40d05d54ff359.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:concourse;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:900;src:url(/static/concourse-black-italic-414b1931eda936f02cd86f4a3c470599.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_3_book-663dbccb9e4dbd910fd466c47520fdbb.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:300;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_3_book_italic-9231808e49169f2b71e3308a5f80a6bc.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_4_medium-cd0197b0b09d8de403bf6f9aebef40d7.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:500;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_4_medium_italic-ae7d97d5064ad9ace94f9b3ef08e45a8.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_6_semibold-b9819ffa2efa8b950da5d37461c81183.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_6_semibold_italic-a253c05527c67ddc3083454db26f1406.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:900;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_8_black-5451d90fb866a9398f998ac8e927fb5d.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-feature-settings:"ss02";font-display:auto;font-family:heliotrope;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:900;src:url(/static/heliotrope_ot_8_black_italic-32ef7278c20a0e4da4644495ac796202.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:valkyrie;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:oldstyle-nums;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/valkyrie_ot_b_regular-8d794b0a29518d51621e3f275709a091.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:valkyrie;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:oldstyle-nums;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/valkyrie_ot_b_italic-4952a5358fbf8f06426b49f4bab5fa22.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:valkyrie;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-variant-numeric:oldstyle-nums;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/valkyrie_ot_b_bold-a2b27d620c24717adb821bd5a8d2e595.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:valkyrie;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-variant-numeric:oldstyle-nums;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/valkyrie_ot_b_bold_italic-651bee8b362e5dc204e9529c4124ae9c.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:triplicate;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/triplicate_ot_a_regular-18445def6d3c444928c0da898169a2df.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:triplicate;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(/static/triplicate_ot_a_italic-7eca88d397ccf9d4b58fab740ce9474e.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:triplicate;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/triplicate_ot_a_bold-841d415a1bbcbe1d17da97697b2f50e3.woff2) format("woff2")}@font-face{font-display:auto;font-family:triplicate;font-stretch:normal;font-style:italic;font-weight:700;src:url(/static/triplicate_ot_a_bold_italic-d60f0e3439fe5bd0f78b2a2162d62c61.woff2) format("woff2")}:root{--dark-gray:#333;--blue-gray:#6b6e7a;--light-gray:#818181;--link-text:#b22222;--link-background:#fff5f5;--serif:"Heliotrope","Georgia",serif;--sans-serif:"Concourse","Helvetica",sans-serif;--monospace:"Triplicate","Courier",monospace}html{text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;-webkit-font-feature-settings:"liga","kern";font-feature-settings:"liga","kern";font-family:var(--serif);font-size:2.4vw;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}img{width:100%}@media (max-width:320px){html{font-size:17px}}@media (max-width:520px){html{font-size:19px}}@media (min-width:1000px){html{font-size:22px}}body{margin:1rem 0;padding:0}.article-list,.blog-list,.index-page,article>div,aside,blockquote,figcaption,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hr,nav,ol,p,table,ul{margin:0 auto;max-width:25rem}figcaption{margin-left:0}@media (max-width:520px){.article-list,.blog-list,.index-page,article>aside,article>blockquote,article>div,article>h1,article>h2,article>h3,article>h4,article>h5,article>h6,article>hr,article>ol,article>p,article>table,article>ul,figcaption,figure.datawrapper,figure.small,main>div,main>h1,nav{margin-left:1.34rem;margin-right:1.34rem}}@media (min-width:768px){.about-me,.article-list,.blog-list{padding-bottom:8rem}}@media (max-width:1080px){figure.large figcaption,figure.xlarge figcaption{margin-left:1.3rem}}figure.medium,figure.youtube{max-width:32rem}figure.large{max-width:48rem}figure.xlarge{max-width:52rem}figure.full{max-width:none}figure.medium,figure.small{margin-bottom:2rem;margin-top:2.4rem}figure.large,figure.xlarge{margin-bottom:2.2rem;margin-top:2.8rem}figure.datawrapper{margin-bottom:2.6rem;margin-top:2.6rem}figure.youtube{margin-bottom:3rem;margin-top:3rem;padding-left:1.3rem;padding-right:1.3rem}@media (max-width:520px){figure.large,figure.medium,figure.xlarge{margin-bottom:1.6rem;margin-top:1.8rem}}article li,p{font-size:1rem;font-variant-numeric:proportional-nums;line-height:1.42;margin-bottom:.9rem}li,ul{list-style:none;padding:0}article ol,article ul{counter-reset:foobar;margin-bottom:1.5rem;margin-top:1.5rem;padding:0}article li{margin-bottom:.8em}article ol li{margin-left:2.8rem}article ul li{margin-left:1.8rem}article ul li:before{color:#444;content:"•";margin-left:-1.8rem;position:absolute}article ol li:before{content:counter(foobar);counter-increment:foobar;font-family:Concourse-index;font-size:120%;margin-left:-2.8rem;margin-top:-.1em;position:absolute}figure.datawrapper h2{color:var(--blue-gray);font-family:var(--sans-serif);font-size:90%;font-variant:normal;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:1.2rem;padding-right:2rem;text-transform:none}figcaption{color:var(--blue-gray);font-size:80%;line-height:1.36;margin-top:.8rem}figcaption span:first-child{margin-right:.34rem}aside cite,figcaption span:last-child{color:var(--light-gray);font-size:80%;font-style:normal}.front-cover{display:block;height:100vh!important;margin:0 0 3rem;max-height:100vh;overflow:hidden;width:100vw!important}.front-cover img,.front-cover video{height:100vh!important;-o-object-fit:cover;object-fit:cover;-o-object-position:center;object-position:center;width:100vw!important}.front-cover .text{margin:0 auto;position:absolute;right:2rem;top:-6rem}.front-cover h1,.front-cover p{max-width:25rem;text-shadow:-1px 1px 0 #333,-1px 2px 0 #0a0e27}.front-cover h1{border:none;color:#fff;font-size:300%;font-weight:600;margin-bottom:0}.front-cover p{color:#fff;font-size:110%;line-height:1.4;margin-left:0;margin-top:-.2rem}@media (max-width:768px){.front-cover{height:100%!important;margin-top:-1.4rem!important;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%!important}.front-cover img,.front-cover video{height:100%!important;-o-object-fit:contain;object-fit:contain;width:100%!important}.front-cover .text{left:auto;margin:3rem 1.3rem 0;position:relative;top:auto}.front-cover .text h1,.front-cover .text p{font-size:1rem;margin:0 auto;max-width:25rem;text-shadow:none}.front-cover .text h1{font-size:210%;line-height:1.1;margin-bottom:.2rem}.front-cover .text p{font-size:125%;line-height:1.3}}@media (max-width:520px){.front-cover .text{margin-top:1.2rem}}blockquote{margin-bottom:2rem;margin-top:2rem}blockquote p{border-left:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:1.6rem;padding-left:.8rem}.byline{color:var(--dark-gray);font-family:var(--sans-serif);letter-spacing:.01em;margin-bottom:1.4rem;margin-top:2.4rem}p+.byline{margin-bottom:1.6rem;margin-top:1.6rem}@media (max-width:520px){.byline{margin-top:1.6rem}}.byline address{font-size:75%;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;margin-bottom:.66rem}.byline address a{color:currentColor;text-decoration:underline;-webkit-text-decoration-color:#ccc;text-decoration-color:#ccc;text-underline-offset:1px}.byline time{display:block;font-size:70%;font-variant-numeric:lining-nums;font-weight:500}aside{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;border-top:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:2.4rem;margin-top:2.4rem;padding-bottom:.1rem;padding-top:.8rem}aside label,aside li,aside p{color:var(--blue-gray)}aside li,aside p{font-size:85%;line-height:1.4;margin-bottom:.7rem}aside label{display:block;font-size:80%;font-weight:700;letter-spacing:.01em;margin-bottom:.2rem}aside h2{margin-bottom:.8rem;margin-top:0}@media (max-width:520px){aside{margin-bottom:2rem;margin-top:2rem}}aside.warning{background:#ff3;border:none}aside.warning p{color:#000;padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem}.comments{margin-top:3rem}.comments h3{border-bottom:4px double #ccc;margin-bottom:.8rem;margin-left:25%;margin-right:25%;padding-bottom:.7rem;text-align:center}.comments ul{margin-top:0}.comments li{font-size:95%;margin-left:2.5rem}.comments li:before{content:"•";font-family:concourse-index;margin-left:-2.5rem;position:absolute}hr{border-top:2px solid red;margin-bottom:2rem;margin-top:2rem}.big-question{font-size:120%;font-weight:600;margin-bottom:1.2rem;margin-top:1.2rem}a{color:var(--link-text);text-decoration:none}a:hover,a span:hover{background:var(--link-background);transition:.2s ease-in-out}code{font-family:var(--monospace);font-size:95%;padding-left:.2em;padding-right:.2em}.small-caps{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"c2sc";font-feature-settings:"c2sc"}.small-caps,nav{font-variant:small-caps;text-transform:lowercase}nav{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"c2sc";font-feature-settings:"c2sc";color:var(--dark-gray);font-family:var(--sans-serif);font-weight:400}nav li{display:inline}nav a{color:#333}nav a:hover{color:#000}nav.top{border-bottom:1px dotted gray;margin-bottom:.24rem;margin-top:6rem;padding-bottom:.14rem}nav.bottom{margin-top:6rem;padding-bottom:4rem}nav.bottom ul{border-top:1px dotted gray;margin-top:1rem}@media (max-width:520px){nav.top{margin-top:0}nav.bottom{margin-top:4rem;padding-bottom:3rem}}h1{font-family:var(--sans-serif);font-size:1.8rem;font-weight:300;letter-spacing:-.02em;line-height:1.1;margin-bottom:1.6rem}h1+p{font-size:115%;font-weight:100;margin-bottom:1.24rem;margin-top:.8rem}@media (max-width:520px){h1{margin-bottom:1.6rem;margin-top:0}h1.page-title{margin-bottom:3rem}}h1>a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}h2{font-size:110%;font-weight:600;line-height:1.36;margin-bottom:.6rem;margin-top:2.2rem}@media (max-width:520px){h2{margin-top:1.8rem}}@media (min-width:768px){figure+h2{margin-top:2.6rem}}h3{-webkit-font-feature-settings:"c2sc" 1;font-feature-settings:"c2sc" 1;font-size:100%;font-variant:small-caps;font-weight:700;margin-bottom:.5rem;margin-top:1.6rem;text-transform:lowercase}article>li,article>p{hyphenate-limit-before:3;hyphenate-limit-after:3;hyphenate-limit-chars:6 3 3;hyphenate-limit-lines:2;hyphenate-limit-last:always;hyphenate-limit-zone:8%;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before:3;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after:3;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-chars:6 3 3;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines:2;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-last:always;-webkit-hyphenate-limit-zone:8%;-moz-hyphenate-limit-chars:6 3 3;-moz-hyphenate-limit-lines:2;-moz-hyphenate-limit-last:always;-moz-hyphenate-limit-zone:8%;-ms-hyphenate-limit-chars:6 3 3;-ms-hyphenate-limit-lines:2;-ms-hyphenate-limit-last:always;-ms-hyphenate-limit-zone:8%;hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;-moz-hyphens:auto;-ms-hyphens:auto}.black,.front-cover p,.medium,.no-hyphens,.small-caps,b,cite,code,em,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,i,strong{hyphens:none;-moz-hyphens:none;-ms-hyphens:none;-webkit-hyphens:none}h1.page-title{margin-bottom:3rem}.all-tags{padding-bottom:6rem}.blog-list article{margin-bottom:1rem}.blog-list h2{font-weight:400;line-height:1.34;margin-bottom:.72rem;margin-top:0}@media (max-width:520px){.all-tags,.blog-list{padding-bottom:2rem}.blog-list article{margin-bottom:1.8rem}}.article-list time,.blog-list time,.tags,.tags a{color:var(--dark-gray);font-family:var(--sans-serif);font-weight:500}.article-list time,.blog-list time{display:block;font-size:.74rem;letter-spacing:.01em;margin-bottom:0}.tags{-webkit-column-gap:.54rem;column-gap:.54rem;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-bottom:.4rem;margin-top:.74rem}.tags label{border:1px solid #dfdfdf;border-radius:4px;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;font-size:.66rem;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:.02em;margin-bottom:.5rem;padding:.22rem .28rem}.tags label:first-letter{text-transform:uppercase}.index-page{margin-top:28vh}.index-page ul{margin-bottom:.2rem;max-width:none}.index-page ul li{color:var(--blue-gray);font-family:var(--serif);font-size:125%;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:.1rem}.index-page h1{font-size:400%;letter-spacing:-.04em}@media (max-width:520px){.index-page h1{font-size:280%}}.article-list article{margin-bottom:1.6rem;margin-top:0;max-width:22rem}.article-list time{display:block;font-size:75%;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:.02em;margin-bottom:.3rem}.article-list h2{font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin-top:0}.article-list article h2{margin-left:0}</style>
   <meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 4.4.0">
   <style>.gatsby-image-wrapper{position:relative;overflow:hidden}.gatsby-image-wrapper picture.object-fit-polyfill{position:static!important}.gatsby-image-wrapper img{bottom:0;height:100%;left:0;margin:0;max-width:none;padding:0;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;width:100%;object-fit:cover}.gatsby-image-wrapper [data-main-image]{opacity:0;transform:translateZ(0);transition:opacity .25s linear;will-change:opacity}.gatsby-image-wrapper-constrained{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}</style>
   <noscript>&lt;style&gt;.gatsby-image-wrapper noscript [data-main-image]{opacity:1!important}.gatsby-image-wrapper [data-placeholder-image]{opacity:0!important}&lt;/style&gt;</noscript>
   <script type="module">const e="undefined"!=typeof HTMLImageElement&&"loading"in HTMLImageElement.prototype;e&&document.body.addEventListener("load",(function(e){if(void 0===e.target.dataset.mainImage)return;if(void 0===e.target.dataset.gatsbyImageSsr)return;const t=e.target;let a=null,n=t;for(;null===a&&n;)void 0!==n.parentNode.dataset.gatsbyImageWrapper&&(a=n.parentNode),n=n.parentNode;const o=a.querySelector("[data-placeholder-image]"),r=new Image;r.src=t.currentSrc,r.decode().catch((()=>{})).then((()=>{t.style.opacity=1,o&&(o.style.opacity=0,o.style.transition="opacity 500ms linear")}))}),!0);</script>
   <link rel="sitemap" type="application/xml" href="/sitemap/sitemap-index.xml">
   <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var hash = window.decodeURI(location.hash.replace('#', ''))
        if (hash !== '') {
          var element = document.getElementById(hash)
          if (element) {
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop
            var clientTop = document.documentElement.clientTop || document.body.clientTop || 0
            var offset = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + scrollTop - clientTop
            // Wait for the browser to finish rendering before scrolling.
            setTimeout((function() {
              window.scrollTo(0, offset - 0)
            }), 0)
          }
        }
      })
   </script>
   <link rel="icon" href="/favicon-32x32.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546" type="image/png">
   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="48x48" href="/icons/icon-48x48.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/icon-72x72.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="/icons/icon-96x96.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/icon-144x144.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="/icons/icon-192x192.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="/icons/icon-256x256.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="/icons/icon-384x384.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="/icons/icon-512x512.png?v=429f78c1f3dc5d93dc42e43688e99546">
   <title>Somme blir meir liberale med åra, men for Paal Kloster (SV) har utviklinga vore motsett • Magnus Kolstad</title>
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:type" content="website">
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" name="twitter:card" content="summary">
   <meta data-react-helmet="true" name="twitter:creator" content="KolstadMagnus">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/webpack-runtime-95b88ae9533d96786098.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/framework-e413e527015be9a1bdfd.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/app-b1e7242108012da03ecd.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/commons-8da364920b56025cdfc9.js">
   <link as="script" rel="preload" href="/component---src-pages-index-js-5118d4ef2ab79253efe6.js">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/index/page-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/sq/d/2774968152.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/app-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <meta name="description" content="58 år på jorda har lært Paal Kloster å forstå folk og komplekse samanhengar. Det har gjeve han ein trong til å stå opp for dei undertrykte i samfunnet." data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:title" content="Somme blir meir liberale med åra, men for Paal Kloster (SV) har utviklinga vore motsett" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta property="og:description" content="58 år på jorda har lært Paal Kloster å forstå folk og komplekse samanhengar. Det har gjeve han ein trong til å stå opp for dei undertrykte i samfunnet." data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:title" content="Somme blir meir liberale med åra, men for Paal Kloster (SV) har utviklinga vore motsett" data-react-helmet="true">
   <meta name="twitter:description" content="58 år på jorda har lært Paal Kloster å forstå folk og komplekse samanhengar. Det har gjeve han ein trong til å stå opp for dei undertrykte i samfunnet." data-react-helmet="true">
</head>
```

I researched and found people with similar problems. Yet I didn't find anyone with this problem **only** in Chromium browsers.

I know CSS hyphenation works better in Safari and Firefox in general—the above two images also demonstrate how Safari understands more of the CSS—but I've never encountered this before.

What's wrong here? How do I fix this? And why does this only happen in Chromium browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Chromium and macOS—not broken code from my part.

Comment: And it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A great resource for questions like this is the website caniuse. This specific question is here

https://caniuse.com/css-hyphens

As to your specific problem, try setting the lang attribute of your html tag.

```
<html lang="sv">
```

The lang attribute has to be set for certain language features to work correctly across all browsers.

https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/11/hyphenation_wor.html

If I had to guess why Chromium is having this issue and not other browsers - they are likely picking up the lang value from the OS and Chromium isn't. By design Chromium doesn't link into its surroundings tightly which is why it's a popular test browser.

Comment: I see. But I have set the lang for all documents. Adding the -o- prefix did not solve the problem. Nor did swapping article>p for html or body work.

Comment: Try using <div>, not <p> - in the link above it is mentioned that p tags don't always work with hyphen (which would be an implementation bug).

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this on Mac but not on other platforms, this may be https://crbug.com/1267606. If not, I think filing an issue at https://crbug.com/new may help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33089957)